# limit supremum equality

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

2.4.22. Prove that for any positive sequence $\left\{a_{n}\right\}$,
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\varliminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}} \\
\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}}=\frac{1}{\underline{\lim }_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}}
\end{array}
$$
(Here $\left.\frac{1}{+\infty}=0, \frac{1}{0^{+}}=+\infty\right)$.

What does "$\frac{1}{0^{+}}=+\infty$" in the brackets mean in this context? Why isn't it undefined? If I am proving the case that $\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}$ = $0$, can I say that it is equal to $0^+$ so that I can make the factor to become $+\infty$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the brackets you see the definitions. That is why it is not undefined. These definitions are standard for the *positive extended real number line*. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations)

It is
when $\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}$ = $0$ that the in-context meaning of $\frac{1}{0^{+}}=+\infty$ becomes clear, recalling that your sequence is positive. Your first task is then to show that $$\varliminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{a_{n}}=+\infty.$$

When $\varlimsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_{n}$ = $0$  the notation  $0^+$ is appropriate, and makes sense, again keeping in mind that your sequence is positive.

Briefly, that answer to your last question is "yes".